# ajax error Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: request, cross-domain

I am getting this error while I am calling web service from java script. But I am getting perfect response while I am use curl to call this api Please help. I am stuck in this problem

Cross-Origin Request Blocked : The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

```
 $("#target").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer  code here "
        },        
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "https://test.maegan.co:4433/RestoLinkxPluginService.svc/v2/restaurants/74/full-menus.json?menuType=PickUp"        
        })
        .done(function( res ) {
        alert( res );
        });
    });
```

Comment: “_Cross-Origin Request_ Blocked : The _Same Origin Policy_ disallows reading the remote resource” – your research keywords are contained in that message already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS on the server side, [like this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), specifically the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.